# Problem with adding src attribute to template tag in Vuejs + Laravel

Tags: laravel, typescript, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I started a project with Vuejs and Laravel using Laravel Mix.
It works for the most part, but when I'm trying to divide my component up into separate files and load them in the .vue file like this:

```
<template src="./comp.html"></template>
<script src="./comp.ts" lang="ts"></script>
<style src="./comp.scss" scoped lang="scss"></style>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
 error  in ./resources/js/components/comp/comp.html?vue&type=template&id=c2090546&scoped=true

Module Error (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js):

VueCompilerError: Unquoted attribute value cannot contain U+0022 ("), U+0027 ('), U+003C (<), U+003D (=), and U+0060 (`).
at /home/geordyd/projects/pension-tool/htdocs/resources/js/components/comp/comp.html:2:35
1  |  // Module
2  |  var code = "<section class=\"comp\">\n  <h1>comp Component</h1>\n</section>\n\n";
   |                                    ^
3  |  // Exports
4  |  module.exports = code;
```

I get this output in the browser:

[image]

package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.3",
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
        "jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.0-beta.14",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
        "postcss": "^8.1.10",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "sass": "^1.29.0",
        "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
        "vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0",
        "vue-loader": "^16.0.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/webpack-env": "^1.16.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "ts-loader": "^8.0.11",
        "typescript": "~3.9.3",
        "vue": "^3.0.3",
        "vue-cli-plugin-vue-next": "^0.1.4"
    }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "esnext",
        "strict": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "types": [
            "webpack-env"
        ]
    },
    "types": [
        "webpack-env"
    ],
    "include": [
        "resources/js/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

webpack.mix.js:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.ts('resources/js/app.ts', 'public/js').vue()
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

I tried downgrading the vue-loader package, but it did not work.

Changing comp.html to `var code = '<section class="comp"><br><h1>comp Component</h1><br></section><br><br>'` gives this as output in the browser:

[image]

Comment: Try with `var code = '<section class="comp"><br><h1>comp Component</h1><br></section><br><br>'` in comp component.

Comment: Where exactly do I put this code?

Comment: At `/home/geordyd/projects/pension-tool/htdocs/resources/js/components/comp/comp.html`.

Comment: I edited my question with your changes

Comment: Have you checked differences against [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html)?

Comment: Yes, I have a project with only Vue where it works, but it doesnt work in combination with laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with Laravel Mix.
The developer already fixed it.

Link to github issue:
https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1893#event-4074240275

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to use `require` in the src.

```
<template :src="require('./comp.html')"></template>
<script :src="require('./comp.ts"') lang="ts"></script>
<style :src="require('./comp.scss"') scoped lang="scss"></style>
```

Comment: When I use require() the error disappears, but the component doesn't load at all.

Comment: maybe the path is wrong? with vue cli i use @, so the path start to the src folder. i don't remember if laravel mix use something like this

Comment: The path should be right, because it loads some html when I'm not using require().

Comment: if you inspect the element in broswer, wich url there is in src?

Comment: Only this one in the script tag: //localhost:8080//js/app.js

Comment: ok, i can't understand where you are doing wrong, at this point i think is something in ts.config.js, but i can't say you what...so i hope someone will help you

Comment: Yes maybe it is, thanks for helping though.